# DispatchTimer is not firing in the "Release" mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

We have developed an application in WPF. This application should be refreshed on particular time interval, so we have used the the "DispatchTimer" control.

The following code is used to do this refresh process.

```
 private void PageReferesh()
    {
        try
        {

            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = App.dirctedWorkTaskTimer;
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            // throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
    protected void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GetOperatorDetails();
        GetCustomers();

    }
```

It is working fine in the development environment. When we change to "Release Mode" and deploy to another folder on the same system, it doesn't work.

Actually, the same is working in "Release" mode, running from he VS2012 IDE. it does not work while copy the "Release" folder (bin/release) to some other file path.

Comment: What doesn't work, is the timer starting? We would need to see the eventHandler code as well, to see if it is being called and stalling somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your review. I hope below code is what you want

Comment: Where does the `dirctedWorkTaskTimer` initialized? and don't swallow exceptions. Log it for future reference. Remove the try/catch and see whether the exception is thrown.

Comment: Good suggesion that remove the "try/catch" option. I did it. However, it is not working. Actually, the same is working in "Release" mode, running from he VS2012 IDE. it does not work while copy the "Release" folder to some other file path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `DispatcherTimer` you have does not run on the main UI dispatcher. 
if not what is the `DispatcherPriority` (It should not be `ApplicationIdle` either) that you have set when creating the `DispatcherTimer` instance ?
Based on that if the Timer runs on the main UI dispatcher with a less priority it might no run to completion as expected depending on other higher priority operation that might be lined up in the UI dispatcher's pumping stack.

I recommend something like below

```
        Dispatcher _uiRefreshDispatcher;
        //Make sure calling thread is UI thread
        Dispatcher _uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    private void PageRefresh()
    {
        var waitForRefreshWatchThread = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

        var messageThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            _uiRefreshDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            waitForRefreshWatchThread.Set();
            Dispatcher.Run();
            waitForRefreshWatchThread.Dispose();
        }) { Name = "RefresherThread", IsBackground = true };
        messageThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        messageThread.Start();

        waitForRefreshWatchThread.Wait();

        var refreshTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Send, _uiRefreshDispatcher);
        refreshTimer.Tick += OnRefreshTimeElapsed;
        refreshTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    }

    private void OnRefreshTimeElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_uiDispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            _uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<object, EventArgs>)OnRefreshTimeElapsed, sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            //Update UI here
        }
    }
```